# Update data from RSS with vbscript

Tags: vbscript, rss

I'm writing a VBScript file (*.vbs) that should get data from this [RSS](https://www.cba.am/_layouts/rssreader.aspx?rss=280F57B8-763C-4EE4-90E0-8136C13E47DA) and export them to text file. I searched the internet but found nothing about this. 
Does anyone know any sources to use for creating such function ?

P.S. The RSS just shows the currency rates for a date. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started, in [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript) you can

1. Load the data into a `DomDocument`, as RSS is XML

```vb
Option Explicit

dim xmldoc: set xmldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.6.0")
xmldoc.async = false
xmldoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmldoc.load "https://www.cba.am/_layouts/rssreader.aspx?rss=280F57B8-763C-4EE4-90E0-8136C13E47DA"
```

2. Run a query to get what you want using XPath

```vb
  ' obviously, you need to change this to your requirements
  ' here, we're just getting every item node
  dim items: set items = xmldoc.selectNodes("//item")
```

3. Output the text to file

```vb
dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim stream: set stream = fso.OpenTextFile("data.txt", 2, true)
dim item
for each item in items
    ' again, this changes to your requirements
    ' this just writes the text content of all the items and child
    ' nodes
    stream.WriteLine item.text
next 'item
stream.Close
```